# Not Sure why this doesn't return the index of the element?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

Not sure why this doesn't return te index of the searched element. Input is the sorted array, its size and the element to be found.

```
int binarySearch(int a[], int size, int key){
  int mid = (size)/2;
  if(a[mid] == key){
    return mid;
  }else if(size ==1 || size ==0){
      return -1;
  }

  if(key<a[mid]){
    return binarySearch(a, mid, key);
  }else if (key > a[mid]){
    return binarySearch(a+(mid), size-mid, key);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're learning C++, please make an effort to learn the Standard Library and things like `std::vector`. Passing around array pointer/size pairs is just a giant mess.

Comment: The correct way to find the answer to your question is by using a debugger.

Comment: Please provide a small failing example (i.e., the contentes of `a` and the value of `key`).

Comment: @tadman actually i am doing an online course and the answer is in modular formso can't change the return type.

Comment: Ah, yes, yet another C++ "course" that only teaches nonsense. I hope this is just an assignment and that you can survive it without sponging up these toxically bad habits.

Comment: Lol. I know. But its not a c++ course but a competetive programming course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `key > a[mid]`, you have to return `mid + binarySearch(a+(mid), size-mid, key)`, as the binarySearch will only see the second half of the array and thus return an index into the second half.